# How to use a variable when making a lambda expression using Expression.Lambda<Func<>>()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a linq query which is as follows:

```
var query = _appDbContext.Persons
                .Where(p => p.Id == 123)
                .Select(lambda)
                .ToList();
```

I use lambda because i have a variable in my select statement. The lambda:

```
var wantedData = "Adress";

var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, wantedData);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, Adress>>(body, x);
```

The query will return the addresses for person with id 123. Let's say instead of the addresses I would like to recieve all subscriptions this person has. Only setting `wantedData = "Subscription"` will not work, because of the "Adress" in the lambda statement. So I'm looking for a way to use a variable to change "Adress" in the lambda statement.

I tried the following, which obviously does not work.

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, wantedData>>(body, x);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you not just querying like this?
`var addresses= _appDbContext.Persons.Where(p => p.Id == 123).Select(p => p.Address).ToList();`

Comment: @MarianSimonca Because I want my query to get either adresses or subscribtions, based on a variable. With a query like yours I would have to build two queries for this.

Comment: But you could have this query inside a method that has an Expression parameter. When calling that function you basically pass what properties you want to get trough that query

Comment: @MarianSimonca I'm new to querying with linq so I could be wrong but is that not what I'm already doing with assigning a value to var x?

Comment: Yes, it is something similar, but a bit more complicated, I am trying to put up an example for you to try

Comment: @TimMG My previous answer had a mistake, so I deleted. After fixed it, I undeleted. Check it now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to create a generic query method that takes an Expression as parameter.

EDIT: This will receive a string value and will try to match it with an existing property on your `Person` class.

```
private IEnumerable<TResult> GetPersonData<TResult>(Expression<Func<Person, TResult>> selectExpression)
{
    return _dbContext.Persons
            // .Where(filter)
        .Select(selectExpression)
        .ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetData(string dataPropertyName)
{
    switch(dataPropertyName) {
         case nameof(Person.Address): return GetPersonData(p => p.Address);
         case nameof(Person.Subscription): return GetPersonData(p => p.Subscription);
         // other cases
         default: throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid property name");
    }
}
```

*note that this code is just an example written on the spot and it might not work directly with copy-paste*

Comment: This works, but doesn't really solve the problem. I still have to make a function for each call. I would like to give the data I want to receive as a parameter like this: `GetPersonData("Adress")` Is that possible?

Comment: You can call this method with any navigation property for Person. I created two methods just to exemplify how to call `GetPersonData` in different scenarios

Comment: I understand, but it is not possible to this: `var wantedData = "Adress"` and then call the function like this: `GetPersonData(p => p.wantedData)`

Comment: As you can see, `GetPersonData(p => p.Address)` is specifying what you want to receive and this version is safer since you are not passing any magic string as parameter and if you change the name of `Address` property it will work as well

Comment: Well, you don't need the `wantedData` variable anymore because you don't need to create a `lambda` variable anymore

Comment: The problem is I am recieving the `wantedData` as a parameter in my API call and I want to send the corresponding data back to the client. There are a lot of different sets of data that could be requested, so making a function for each of these would not be nice

Comment: It works, however, I'm still looking for a way to do it with passing in a parameter. That would make a difference of 25 lines of switch statement. If I don't find a solution like that, I will surely use your solution. Thanks for the help! (:

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar to an `OrderBy` and tweak it a little for your select. This only works if you know the return type.
You can create an extension method with the following code:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<T,TResult>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == propertyName.ToUpper());
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(pe, prop.Name);

    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });

    MethodCallExpression selectCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Select",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, prop.PropertyType },
        source.Expression,
        lambda);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(selectCallExpression);
}
```

That way, you can use it like:

```
var query = _appDbContext.Persons
                .Where(p => p.Id == 123)
                .Select<Person,string>(wantedData)
                .ToList();
```